# How can client browser console log be forwarded to backend through REST api in angular 4 application?

Tags: angular, typescript

How can client browser console log be forwarded to the backend through REST api in angular 4 application? My requirement is to send all logs to backend (Console.log, console.error, console.warn).

I tried the following options:

1. stacktrace js. But there is very less doc available for angular application integration. Moreover, it logs only errors.
2. custom error handling - that also logs only errors.

Any help with a small example is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You would need to POST whatever value you were going to output via the console.

Comment: Yes.  I would just try to filer on console functions .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the console log functions. I've never done that, so this code probably won't work, but it gives you something to work on.

Override those functions at the start of your application to be sure to apply them everywhere.

```js
@NgModule(...)
export class AppModule() {
  constructor() {
    window.console.log = (...args) => {
      // Make your HTTP call here
      console.log(...args);
    };
  }
}
```

If it is a read-only property, try redefining it :

```js
Object.defineProperty(window.console, 'log', { writable: true, value: (...args) => {
  // HTTP call
  console.log(...args);
}
```